# VB Translation of a C# assignment

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can anyone translate this into Visual Basic? (Mostly it works, but for the @ symbol. What is the VB equivalent?)

```
private static string desktop = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile") + @"\Desktop\";
```

Comment: Just remove @,  if still not working, try replace "\" with "\\"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# `@"\string"` behavior is how VB.Net works by default. You just remove the `@`:

```
Private Shared desktop As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\"
```

Though you should prefer `Path.Combine()` in both VB.Net and C#, which looks like this:

```
Private Shared desktop As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile"), "Desktop")
```

This helps your code port automatically to places that might use a different directory separator (like linux/Mac, which use `/` instead of `\`).

But Windows also has something called "Folder Redirection". By default, the `Desktop` folder is named "Desktop" and located just below the user's profile folder, but *this isn't guaranteed*. It's actually fairly common in business environments for these folders to be redirected to a network share on a server somewhere so the files can be backed up easily. You really should be looking here:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Which, again, should also work if this code ever needs to port to a different platform, even one where the folder structure is wildly different (say, a Mac, Gnome, KDE or Enlightenment machine).